# How to push down second dropdown when open first ?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

here is my question :

How I can push down the second dropdown menu when I hover over first(they are one below another)?

here is my css :

```
#navMenu{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navMenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 30px;
}

#navMenu li{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#navMenu ul li{
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
display: block;
color:#eee;
background: #444;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
#navMenu ul ul{
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
top: 30px;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul{
visibility: visible;
}
```

Thank you all.. With this css when I hover over first menu it get over the second and words just get mixed .. If you know what I am trying to say ...

Comment: Share a fiddle that reproduces your problem. It's impossible to help you right now.

Comment: Missing some pieces of the puzzle here.

Comment: Here is the fiddle , but in my browser they are one below another ...http://jsfiddle.net/redrum96/h2scv93e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for something like this, you'll need the help of jQuery to push the second meunu down. heres the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h2scv93e/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu1').hover(function() {
        $('.wrapper2').toggleClass('top100');
    });
});

.top100 {
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few changes are necessary in your code to achieve this.

First of all, change your duplicate IDs for classes. IDs **must** be unique in the page. And set different ids for your 'navMenu', like 'navMenu-1' and 'navMenu-2'.

After that, remove the background's opacity in your lis:

```
.navMenu ul li {
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    color:#eee;
    background: #888; // change for your desired color
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2); // remove this line
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

Last of all, just set a z-index in your first menu. That will keep this menu over the second one:

```
#navMenu-1 ul li:hover ul {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h2scv93e/1/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!